# How to build simple polymer webcomponent so it's reusable?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

So, I want to include several unrelated webcomponents in one html page and we are trying to do so with Polymer.

Each webcomponent on it's own is working fine but combining multiple of them is causing a lot of headache.

What did I do to show the problem:

- create two webcomponents with polymer init and choose `polymer-3-element`
- make sure they have different names 

   `window.customElements.define('test-element-a', TestElement);
   window.customElements.define('test-element-b', TestElement);`

I now want to build and bundle them (since my components have some dependencies) into 1 js file... and this is where I'm stuck. I tried with the following polymer.json:

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "test-element.js",
  "npm": true,
  "lint": {
    "rules": [
      "polymer-3"
    ]
  },
  "builds": [
      { 
        "name": "es6prod",
        "preset": "es6-bundled",
        "addServiceWorker": false,
        "bundle": {
          "inlineCss": true,          
          "inlineScripts": false,      
          "rewriteUrlsInTemplates": true, 
          "sourcemaps": true,     
          "stripComments": true
        }
      }
      ]
}
```

So, now I created a simple webpage where I'd like to include them:

```
<html>
    <head><script>/*a whole lot of javascript so the define function is available*/</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing multiple polymer components</h1>

        <test-element-a></test-element-a>
        <test-element-b></test-element-b>

        <script type="module" src="./polymer-element-a/build/es6prod/test-element.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="./polymer-element-b/build/es6prod/test-element.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here I have the problem that only the first webcomponent loads... for the second, an error is available in the console:

```
(index):2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at http://127.0.0.1:8081/polymer-element-b/build/es6prod/test-element.js:1:4222
    at f (http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:10783)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:10676
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:11004)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:10639)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:12620
    at j (http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:11604)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8081/:2:12602
```

If I dig deeper, this is because the following happens twice:
`customElements.define("dom-module",DomModule)`, once for every component.

So, my question: how to build polymer webcomponents so that we can make them reusable?

Comment: you cannot define 2 different custom elements with the same class (TestElement)

Comment: actually you can - I found out that the bundling part causes the troubles thanks to the lovely people on the polymer slack channel. The example above is already working without bundling, I'm now trying it in our more complex build.

Comment: in this case i guess it's not the same class but 2 different ones with the same name define in 2 different contexts

Comment: The problem was caused by bundling and this the customElement dom-module was added twice.
If you don't bundle and because of browser caching, it will only download the dom-module element once and execute it only once.
This has solved my issue...